# Convert command output to csv, with time stamp

Tags: command-line, text-processing, timestamps, csv-simple

I want to test a speed connection with terminal command:

```
./speedtest-cli
```

And it returns This:

```
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Testing from Moscow, Russia (77.50.8.74)...
Selecting best server based on latency...
Hosted by East Telecom Ltd (Mytishchi) [10.81 km]: 7.433 ms
Testing download speed........................................
Download: 38.06 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed..................................................
Upload: 23.52 Mbit/s
```

I want to transform this to csv row like :

```
12-12-2016 12:01 ; 38.06 ; 23.52 ;
12-12-2016 12:11 ; 39.00 ; 21.12 ;
12-12-2016 12:21 ; 37.06 ; 25.00 ;
```

I'm trying to use simple grep function for this:

```
grep 'Upload:' test.txt | sed 's/^.*: //'  >> test_res.txt
```

But this is just to get speed number from file, and only rewrite one of the params. How to write exact transformation to needed format. I'm rather new in bash scripting.

Comment: exactly. I want to make excel table formatted file, like csv, with 3 columns. 1) date+ time
2) download speed
3) upload speed

Thats it. In my examle I wrote only date, but this script would be running each 5-10 minutes, so time is important

Comment: edited the time stamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk  -v date="$(date +%d-%m-%Y\ %H:%M)" -v OFS=';' '/Download:/ { d=$2; }
     /Upload:/ { print date, d, $2, ""; d="" }' speedtest
```

Comment: 1) I would use it with the exact command running, like "./speedtest-cli | awk -v ....." and as i tested, it works, but can you make the date real time. I mean to place there the real date+time like in my example

Comment: awk -v date="$(date)" OFS=';' '/Download:/ { d=$2; }
                /Upload:/ { print date , d, $2, ""; d="" }' speed

Comment: ./speedtest-cli | awk -v date="$(date)" OFS=';' '/Download:/ { d=$2; }
                /Upload:/ { print date, d, $2, ""; d="" }'
shows 1 line syntax error

Comment: It needs to be `awk -v date="$(date)" -v OFS=';'`. Note the second `-v`.

Comment: Works fine. But how can I format date here to the numbers only?

Comment: `date +%d-%m-%Y`

Comment: What is the correct way of getting time ?

Comment: You mean wall-clock time? `date +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"`

Comment: Well, yes. I've found the correct format on this site. But thank you ! I did what i wanted. now it is on crontab and i'm getting my analytic data

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ready solution:
Download the speedtest-csv script and Give it execute permission:

```
wget -O speedtest-csv https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HenrikBengtsson/speedtest-cli-extras/master/bin/speedtest-csv

chmod +x speedtest-csv
```

Next move speedtest-csv to /usr/bin/

```
mv speedtest-csv /usr/bin/
```

Generate CSV header

```
speedtest-csv --header >> /var/www/html/speedtest.csv
```

Then, modify output for your needs, e.g. change the last line to:

```
echo $start ";" $upload ";" $download
or
echo $start "Upload:" $upload "Download" $download
```

**UPDATE**

I'm attaching modified script which results the following:

```
bash speedtest-csv
2016-06-03 14:12:21 Upload: 258.19 Mbit/s Download 242.71 Mbit/s
```

[enter link description here](http://pastebin.com/xxDc1K3M)

Comment: The script is "speedtest-cli" and writted on python. I cannot modify it, because it must be a "clean test" without rewriting this files that i obtained from speedtest server.

Comment: modify the output of the 'speedtest-csv' script. it's written in a bash.

Comment: I have no speedtest-csv script

Comment: it is shown in my post how to get it : "wget -O speedtest-csv ....."

Comment: Ok, i downloaded yours sacript, but it doesn't show the uploaad or download speed at all. Only date+ time

Comment: 'speedtest-csv' is an extra script executes 'speedtest_cli.py', gets its ouput which you can modify for your needs by simple running the command

Comment: I;ve updated the post with a new link

Comment: speedtest-cli: command not found . If i'm not mistaken, there must be absolute path or the enviroments must be set...

Comment: add on the 17line:
speedtest-cli=`which speedtest-cli`
and then change on 132 line:
from speedtest-cli to $speedtest-cli